# Passing data via service not updating second controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use service in AngularJS and pass data from one controller to another on click of a button.
I tried and can see that service value is updated but I am unable to retrieve in the second controller, however, I can retrieve in the first Controller.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body ng-app="myApp">

        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <p>Search:<input type="text" ng-model="newValue"></p>
            <button ng-click="myFunc(newValue)">OK</button>

        </div>
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl2">
            {{receivedVal}}            
        </div>


        <script>
       var app= angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl',  function($scope,sharedProperties) {


            $scope.stringValue = sharedProperties.getString();

                $scope.myFunc = function(newValue) {  

                sharedProperties.setString(newValue);
                $scope.stringValue = sharedProperties.getString();
                console.log($scope.stringValue);
               //I am getting the value here by calling sharedProperties.getString();

                };

        });


        app.controller('myCtrl2',  function($scope,sharedProperties) {
            $scope.receivedVal = sharedProperties.getString();
            console.log($scope.receivedVal);
//But I am not getting the updated value here by calling sharedProperties.getString();
        });


        app.service('sharedProperties', function() {
        var stringValue = 'firstoccurence';     
        return {
            getString: function() {
                return stringValue;
            },
            setString: function(value) {
                stringValue = value;
            },        
        }
    });



        </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

**receivedVal** is always coming blank even service is getting updated.

Comment: There is no reason why it should update. `$scope.receivedVal` is not going to reinitialise magically.

Comment: I am sorry if my understanding is wrong but  `sharedProperties.setString(newValue);` should do that.

Comment: The relationship between ctrl and ctrl2 is not a two-way data-binding relationship.

Comment: @PoojaMalik Ideally as your both controllers has been already instantiated ;so in myCtrl2 old value i.e. `firstoccurence` should appear. As your both controllers are in same view , you may need to use `$scoe.$broadcast` and `$scoe.$on()` to listen for value change

Comment: @user1608841 I thought in angular,binding happens automatically :| without listening

Comment: @PoojaMalik https://codepen.io/rahul_naik/pen/VEjxja chk this pen

Comment: @PoojaMalik You may be misunderstanding something.
In you code both controllers view has been instantiated. So in controller 2 ` $scope.receivedVal = sharedProperties.getString();` this will refer to old value `firstoccurence` as from controller one value has not been updated (It will be updated after click OK). Also in controller 2 you are not continuously listening to the changes happening in controller one. You are just accessing the property from service only one time in controller 2. To communicate in such case you need to use $brodcast and $on

Comment: @user1608841 Thanks but then I do not need service if I use broadcast and on?

Comment: @PoojaMalik in this case no need to use service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your HTML code; I can see both the controllers have already been instantiated.

So when you do `$scope.receivedVal = sharedProperties.getString();` in controller 2, you are just getting value from service one time only (**Note :** You are not continuously observing the value from service). And hence in template of controller 2 the default value `firstoccurence` shall be displayed.

You are actually updating the value on click of OK button, which in turns updates value in service. But there is no way you told angular that now as values has been changed then now controller 2 should get this new value.

To active the scenario that you want , you need to use `$broadcast` and `$on` so that you can continuously observe change happening in controller 1.

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body ng-app="myApp">

        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <p>Search:<input type="text" ng-model="newValue"></p>
            <button ng-click="myFunc(newValue)">OK</button>

        </div>
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl2">
            {{receivedVal}}   
            
            
            
            <button ng-click="thisWillGetValFromService()" >update this scope's value</button>
        </div>


        <script>
       var app= angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl',  function($rootScope,$scope,sharedProperties) {


            $scope.stringValue = sharedProperties.getString();

                $scope.myFunc = function(newValue) {  

                sharedProperties.setString(newValue);
                $scope.stringValue = sharedProperties.getString();
                console.log($scope.stringValue);
               //I am getting the value here by calling sharedProperties.getString();
                  $rootScope.$broadcast('greeting', newValue);

                };

        });


        app.controller('myCtrl2',  function($scope,sharedProperties) {
            $scope.receivedVal = sharedProperties.getString();
            console.log($scope.receivedVal);
//But I am not getting the updated value here by calling sharedProperties.getString();
          $scope.$on('greeting', function(ev,val){
               $scope.receivedVal = val
          })


           
        });


        app.service('sharedProperties', function() {
        var stringValue = 'firstoccurence';     
        return {
            getString: function() {
                return stringValue;
            },
            setString: function(value) {
                stringValue = value;
            },        
        }
    });



        </script>

        </body>
```

Above snippet shall solve your problem.

Updated :

Consider a scenario where you have routing configuration defined. So by default only controller 1 and its templates loads in HTML. Then you update ur input box and click OK button. This will save data to service.

Then later on consider on click of some link you re redirecting the app to route of your controller 2 so at this point your controller 2 will get instantiated and `$scope.receivedVal = sharedProperties.getString();` this will give you updated value.

Its just a matter of when you load your template (controller) In your case you load both the controllers at a time so you need to use broadcast and on. But if your second component going to load sometime later then you can always use service.

Comment: Thanks I was wondering than service will never be used.Well thanks.i will dig a bit t more.

Comment: Service can be useful in case of routing where your component will load later on as per routing configuration. See my update answer for service usage

Answer (score 0):

Value is updating in the second controller

But it is not reflecting in the :

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl2">
{{receivedVal}}

</div>
```

Because ng-controller creates new scope

you should write one extra method like in this:
https://codepen.io/amar9312/pen/yRJKGj

Comment: but this will create two button which is not good.I had simple need to transfer data on a click :|